# Изменить цвет SVG при наведении (IsMouseOver)

Tags: wpf, svg, xaml

Есть много способов конвертировать SVG в XAML и использовать их на кнопках, но не понятно каким именно образом можно поменять цвет иконки при наведении на кнопку.

*Пример конвертации:*

```
<Geometry x:Key="myIcon">M1.5 8.13333C1.33431 ...</Geometry>
<Grid x:Key="myIcon2">
    <Viewbox Stretch="Uniform">
        <Path Data="M1.5 8.13333C1.33431 ..." Fill="Green"/>
    </Viewbox>
</Grid>
```

*Пример использования:*

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource btnStyle}">
    <Path Fill="Blue" Data="M1.5 8.13333C1.33431 ..." />
</Button>

<Button Style="{StaticResource btnStyle}" Content="{StaticResource myIcon}"/>
```

*Стиль и триггер кнопки:*

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="btnStyle">  
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Border x:Name="border">
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <!-- Как именно тут менять цвет -->
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Где в вашем стиле хоть намек на то, что там SVG? Замените `ContentPresenter` на `Path`, а цвет его привяжите, например к `Foreground` стиля.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Только учу XAML, не до конца все понимаю.
Заменил так: `<Path Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"/>`
Триггер такой: `<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>`
Кнопка: `<Button Style="{StaticResource btnStyle}"><Path Fill="Blue" Data="{StaticResource myIcon}"/></Button>`
- Так иконка просто вообще не появляется, но если `Data` прописать в `Style`, то все работает. Как правильно вписать эту `Data` в кнопку?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так, смотрите, в вашем стиле `ContentPresenter` является некой абстракцией, неким объектом, который знает, что там должен быть контент, не более того. Это как допустим стиральная машина, которая знает, что внутри у нее должно быть белье, но не знает какого типа оно, какой цвет и так далее, в теории ведь можно заставить ее это понимать, но каким трудом)

У вас по сути 2 варианта:

1. Привязать `Path` к цвету ее родителя:

   - Дописываем у стиля базовый цвет, который меняем триггером:

     ```
     <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="Button.TestStyle">
         <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
         <Setter Property="Template">
             <Setter.Value>
                 <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                     <Border Background="Transparent" >
                         <Viewbox>
                             <ContentPresenter/>
                         </Viewbox>
                     </Border>
                     <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                         <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                             <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                         </Trigger>
                     </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                 </ControlTemplate>
             </Setter.Value>
         </Setter>
     </Style>
     ```
   - У `Path` дописываем свойство `Fill` на нечто подобное:

     ```
     Fill="{Binding Background, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Button}}"
     ```

   Все, теперь `Path` должен менять цвет.
2. Поместить `Path` внутрь стиля. Это, по сути, более правильный вариант, ибо вы перестаете быть зависимы от контента, кнопка становиться самостоятельная.

   ```
    <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="Button.TestStyle">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Border Background="Transparent" >
                        <Viewbox>
                            <Path Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                                    Data="M0.324,1.909c-0.429-0.429-0.429-1.143,0-1.587c0.444-0.429,1.143-0.429,1.587,0l9.523,9.539
                                    l9.539-9.539c0.429-0.429,1.143-0.429,1.571,0c0.444,0.444,0.444,1.159,0,1.587l-9.523,9.524l9.523,9.539
                                    c0.444,0.429,0.444,1.143,0,1.587c-0.429,0.429-1.143,0.429-1.571,0l-9.539-9.539l-9.523,9.539c-0.444,
                                    0.429-1.143,0.429-1.587,0 c-0.429-0.444-0.429-1.159,0-1.587l9.523-9.539L0.324,1.909z" />
                        </Viewbox>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
   ```

Заметьте, что я чуть подправил ваш стиль, `ContentPresenter` обернут в `Viewbox` - это позволяет иконке занять всю площадь кнопки. Также был добавлен `Background` для `Border` - это сделано для того, чтоб триггер срабатывал, когда будет мышь наведется на кнопку, а не на конкретную SVG.

Вот, собственно, и основы. Дальше вы можете это развивать так, как вам угодно, например, вы можете эти страшные крякозябли SVG поместить в ресурсы (нечто на подобии `<Geometry x:Key="Icon.Confirmed">...</Geometry>`). А чтоб не править постоянно стили, можете `Data` привязать к `Content` кнопки (`{TemplateBinding Content}`) и при ее использовании уже писать `<Button Style=".." Content="{StaticResouce Icon.Confirmed}" />`, а чтоб эту портянку постоянно не повторять (не писать стили и так далее), можете сделать свой `UserControl` и будет у вас уже тогда `<ctr:IconButton Icon="Confirmed" />`. В общем, вариантов у вас куча, выбирайте свой и пробуйте реализовать)

Comment: Большущее спасибо за такой подробный ответ! Все получилось.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Хороший, полезный ответ.  **(эти страшные крякозябли SVG)**, не надо так про SVG :)